# php Contact Form on website and reply-to email

Tags: gmail, php, mediatemple

I have a PHP Contact form on a site I am hosing on our mediatemple grid server that was made with Rapidweaver.  It works well except that the email it generates to our info@ourdomain.com is sent as serveradmin@ourdomain.com.  I think the server is just using the trash/blackhole address.  Any way to adjust my php or better yet, the server settings, to send the mail as the reply-to address that the user fills out on the contact form itself?

Why?  Well Google hosts the email for this domain and I wanted to use their canned responses as an auto-responder.  The problem of course, is that the auto-response goes to serveradmin@ourdomain.com and not the user's email address that he filled in on the form.

Thank you for the help!

-Hunter

Answer (score 3):

You can add headers to your mail

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

see [mail phpdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The Reply-to is showing in the headers, but Google's Canned responses use the original sender to respond to.  I would like for it to respond to the email address that the user fills in.  Would I have to adjust this in my php.ini file?  

Something like: sendmail_from = $emailaddress  where $emailaddress is what the user entered on the form.

Am I way off base here?

Thanks!

Comment: no you don't want to change php.ini on the fly. But instead of reply-to put the users mail in the from in $headers? Doesn't that solves it then?

Comment: If it's still sending from serveradmin@yourdomain.com you should take a look at other php email solutions like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872639/good-php-email-library these you can customize more