# Contact form emails do not arrive at destination

Tags: php, forms, email, hosting, contact-form

I have a simple website with a php contact form set up.
The original contact form included:

```
$to = "my_email@gmail.com";

$subject = "New message: $name";
$message = "$message";
$headers = "From: $email";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

but, it never actually sent an emial. My hosting provider claimed they cannot allow such a thing since the way it is, email spoofing can be done. Fine. So, after reading a thread here ([php Contact Form on website and reply-to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106009/php-contact-form-on-website-and-reply-to-email)) I modified the part above to the following:

```
$to = "my_email@gmail.com";


$subject = "New message: $name";
$message = "$message";
$headers = "From: my_email@gmail.com" . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

which worked fine.

Now, I pretty much just uploaded the same site (some design and textual changes, nothing big) under a new domain on the same host (even the same shared hosting server), but it doesn't work. The contact form confirms sending but emails do not arrive.

Any ideas?

Your help would be greatly appreciated :)

---

Update: for what it's worth, here's the full php file:

```
    <?php

// Clean up the input values
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
        $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

    $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}

// Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

// Test input values for errors
$errors = array();
if(strlen($name) < 2) {
    if(!$name) {
        $errors[] = "You must enter a name.";
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Name must be at least 2 characters.";
    }
}
if(!$email) {
    $errors[] = "You must enter an email.";
} else if(!validEmail($email)) {
    $errors[] = "You must enter a valid email.";
}
if(strlen($message) < 10) {
    if(!$message) {
        $errors[] = "You must enter a message.";
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Message must be at least 10 characters.";
    }
}

if($errors) {
    // Output errors and die with a failure message
    $errortext = "";
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        $errortext .= "<li>".$error."</li>";
    }
    die("<span class='failure'><h3>Sorry, The following errors occured:</h3><ol>". $errortext ."</ol><a href='contact.html' class='more'>Refresh Form</a></span>");
}


// --------------------------------------//
// Send the email // INSERT YOUR EMAIL HERE
$to = "myemail@my_domain.com";
// --------------------------------------//


$subject = "Contact Form: $name";
$message = "$message";
$headers = 'From: myemail@my_domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: $email' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Die with a success message
die("<span class='success'><h3>Successfully Sent!</h3> Your message is on its way, we will respond to you shortly.</span>");

// A function that checks to see if
// an email is valid
function validEmail($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
      {
         // character not valid in local part unless 
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
         {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
      if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
      }
   }
   return $isValid;
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked spam folder?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are setting $email, $message etc from the `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables from your form, 
e.g

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

This may still not work if your hosting provider has disabled the php `mail()` from sending emails within `php.ini`

Have you looked into the [php pear mail](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php) function?

It may be worth simply asking your hosting provider for an example of what is allowed. It shouldn't take them more than 5 minutes to write out a sample.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. First off, the hosting provider's support has always been poor. I had a very long exchange with them just in order to find out it was about spoofing. And yes, $email = $_POST["email"]; .  re. pear -I just rather not make big changes. for me it's just more room for mistakes.

Comment: any chance it has to do with either " or ' in the code? e.g. around 'email' ?

Comment: Have you tried just using the mail function itself to rule out all other code possibilities?

`    <?php
    $to = "youremail@my_domain.com";
    $from = "myemail@my_domain.com";
    // --------------------------------------//
    $subject = "Contact Form: test";
    $message = "some test content";
    $headers = 'From: $from' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: $from' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    
    
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>`

Comment: this should be the entire php file ?